# Dialogflow : don't expect user response without ending the conversation

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to make intent on Dialogflow giving an answer but without expecting user response.

I tried the DialogflowConversation close() method but this also ends the conversation, which is not the expected behaviour.

Does anyone have a trick on this ?

Thanks for your returns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [NodeJS client library for Actions on Google](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs)?

If you are, you can use the conv.ask() method, like so:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Hi, how is it going?')
  conv.ask(`Here's a picture of a cat`)
  conv.ask(new Image({
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/imgs/160204193356-01-cat-500.jpg',
    alt: 'A cat',
  }))
})
```

Even though the method name (ask) suggests that it's asking the user a question, calling that method doesn't require a user response, and can be used to simply create an output, like console.log() or print.

One caveat to this, though: if you use the .ask() method and leave the mic open to the user without asking for further input, there's a high chance your Action won't be approved by Google's review process. To account for this, you could provide information, then ask a user if they want further information, like:

```
app.intent('Weather in San Francisco', conv => {
  conv.ask('The weather in San Francisco currently is 56 degrees and rainy.')
  conv.ask(`To hear weather in another city, say the city's name, or say done.`)
})
```

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for your return. 

First of all, yes I use the Nodejs action-on-google lib.

Your explaination is very clear, but I think I did not express myself well : when I said I don't want Dialogflow to expect user response, I meant I don't want the mic to open.

Is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I'm having trouble understanding the value in a voice assistant that doesn't expect user input. What would be an example of a conversation between a user and your app? How would your app know what information is needed?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `conv.add("text")`. This will not open mic.